# Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected

Tags: javascript, post

I am trying to send json to my webmethod but its showing below error.

[image]

Code

```js
function ConsultarNAX_APE(pagina, nrofila, filtro, horas, jsonFiltros, sFiltroPantalla) {
        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", url: "../Servicios/ServiciosJsonTablasReferencia.asmx/CargarNAX_APE",
                data: `{Spagina: '${pagina}',SnroFilas: '${nrofila}',Sfiltro: '${filtro}',Shoras: '${horas}',sOtroFiltro:'${jsonFiltros}',sFiltroPantalla:'${sFiltroPantalla}'}`,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.d.length > 0 && response.d != null) {
                        resolve(response.d);
                    } else {
                        resolve(null);
                    }
                },
                error: fnLlamadaErrorMsg

            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your string is not valid JSON.  Use `JSON.stringify()` instead of building a string by hand.

Comment: JSON requires double quotes (in all keys and all string values) and will not accept single quotes.

Comment: I do not understand, you could help me as I would be with simple quotes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never try to build JSON by hand, create an object or array and use `JSON.stringify`

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    Spagina: pagina,
    SnroFilas: nrofila,
    Sfiltro: filtro,
    Shoras: horas,
    sOtroFiltro:jsonFiltros,
    sFiltroPantalla:sFiltroPantalla
}),
```